# In a JS array of objects, should I use a keys to identify each object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm still learning javascript patterns, and I'm curious about this one.

If I have an array of objects, should I make the array of objects not have keys (Example A), or use their keys (Example B)?

An array of objects without any key:

```
var soylent_green_candidates = [{
  id: 12341,
  name: "Don",
  gender: "Male",
  weapon_of_choice: "Kangaroo Cannon"
},
{
  id: 24325,
  name: "Jimmy",
  gender: "Male",
  weapon_of_choice: "Sushi Blaster"
},
...
]
```

Or an array of objects using the unique ID's as keys:

```
var soylent_green_candidates = [ 
12341: {
  name: "Don",
  gender: "Male",
  weapon_of_choice: "Kangaroo Cannon"
},
24325: {
  name: "Jimmy",
  gender: "Male",
  weapon_of_choice: "Sushi Blaster"
},
...
]
```

Comment: Example 2 is incorrect syntax.

Comment: You can not use an ``identifier`` starting with a number, as used in example 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is invalid, so that should put the question to sleep.

In Javascript you have the option of *arrays*, which are sorted but essentially "key less". Each array entry can only be accessed by its numeric index, period.
The other option is *objects*, which have no guaranteed order but are keyed by arbitrary values.

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
{ foo : 'bar', baz : 42 }
```

You make the choice based on these two criteria, order and requirement for keys.

(Note: while you *can* use arbitrary *numeric* indices for arrays, you can't do so using the literal syntax `[..]`, and it's not usually a good idea. If you need explicit keys, you want objects.)

Comment: Ah, I see. In any case, I imagine poster would be interested in an object keyed by ID.

Comment: Yea exactly, basically I'm reading user objects out of a DB, and want an easy way to grab a particular user. The only unique key for a user is their user_id.

Comment: @Donny Well then it is probably objects you want.